# Flow of execution for FragmentBasics at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Maybe I don't know the first thing about Android app development and `xml` (but I have 3 apps at Google Play Store), but what exactly determines what gets executed when?

To try to answer that question, I inserted `Log` statements in each method in each class file in `FragmentBasics`, which is the downloaded file from the URL in the Title.

Project structure:

[image]

I was surprised to see what the order of execution was.

``````
    MainActivity:      `````onCreate
    HeadlinesFragment: `````onAttach
    HeadlinesFragment: `````onCreate
    AbsListView: checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
    ArticleFragment: `````onCreateView 
    MainActivity: `````fragment_container IS null--two-pane mode
    HeadlinesFragment: `````onStart
    ArticleFragment: `````onStart
``````

Why/how did `onAttach` and `onCreate` in `HeadlinesFragment` and `onCreateView` in `ArticleFragment` get executed before `MainActivty` "fragment container is Null..."?

And why does `HeadlinesFragment` not have `onCreateView` like `ArticleFragment`, but just `onCreate`?

I read that `setContentView` does this: "Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity." Since I was using a "large" device (tablet) and `HeadlinesFragment` and `ArticleFragment` are part of `large\news_articles.xml`, did that `xml` cause the classes to be instantiated?

I really feel like I know next to nothing about Android development. But I have those three apps ...

Here's the essence of the 3 classes mentioned:

``````
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.w("MainActivity","`````onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles); // either normal or large

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) == null)
            Log.w("MainActivity","`````fragment_container IS null--two-pane mode");
        else
        {
            Log.w("MainActivity","`````fragment_container not null--one-pane mode");
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                return;
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager() .beginTransaction()
                                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment)
                                        .commit();
        }
    }
}
``````

.

``````
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.w("HeadlinesFragment","`````onCreate");
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        Log.w("HeadlinesFragment","`````onStart");
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null)
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity _activity)
    {
        Log.w("HeadlinesFragment", "`````onAttach");
        super.onAttach(_activity);
    }
}
``````

.

``````
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _inflater, ViewGroup _container, Bundle _savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.w("ArticleFragment", "`````onCreateView ");
        View v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, _container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        Log.w("ArticleFragment","`````onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }
}
``````

And the essence of the `.xml`:

`article_view.xml`

```
    <TextView     android:id="@+id/article" />
```

`news_articles.xml`

```
    <FrameLayout   android:id="@+id/fragment_container" />
```

`news_articles(large).xml`

```
    <LinearLayout>
        <fragment    
            android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment">

        <fragment   
            android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
            android:id="@+id/article_fragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPCZu.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else already did the same as you, but built also a [nice image](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) with how in practice the lifecycle happens. Here is a [direct reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lxrx.png) to the image diagram.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my questions.... Why/how did onAttach and onCreate in HeadlinesFragment and onCreateView in ArticleFragment get executed before MainActivty "fragment container is Null..."?

And why does HeadlinesFragment not have onCreateView like ArticleFragment, but just onCreate?

Since I was using a "large" device (tablet) and HeadlinesFragment and ArticleFragment are part of large\news_articles.xml, did that xml cause the classes to be instantiated?

Comment: One answer is `HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment`, which "has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView... To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id '@android:id/list'", which the .xml file does not.